# Get norm of numpy sparse matrix rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, norm

I have a sparse matrix that I obtained by using Sklearn's TfidfVectorizer object:

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, analyzer='word', vocabulary=my_vocab, stop_words='english')
tfidf = vect.fit_transform([my_docs])
```

The sparse matrix is (taking out the numbers for generality):

```
<sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

I am trying to get a numeric value for each row to tell me how high a document had the terms I am looking for. I don't really care about which words it contained, I just want to know how many it contained. So I want to get the norm of each or the row*row.T. However, I am having a very hard time working with numpy to obtain this.

My first approach was to just simply do:

```
tfidf[i] * numpy.transpose(tfidf[i])
```

However, numpy will apparently not transpose an array with less than one dimension so that will just square the vector. So I tried doing:

```
tfidf[i] * numpy.transpose(numpy.atleast_2d(tfidf[0]))
```

But numpy.transpose(numpy.atleast_2d(tfidf[0])) still would not transpose the row.

I moved on to trying to get the norm of the row (that approach is probably better anyways). My initial approach was using numpy.linalg.

```
numpy.linalg.norm(tfidf[0])
```

But that gave me a "dimension mismatch" error. So I tried to calculate the norm manually. I started by just setting a variable equal to a numpy array version of the sparse matrix and printing out the len of the first row:

```
my_array = numpy.array(tfidf)
print my_array
print len(my_array[0])
```

It prints out my_array correctly, but when I try to access the len it tells me:

```
IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed
```

I just simply want to get a numeric value of each row in the sparse matrix returned by fit_transform. Getting the norm would be best. Any help here is very appreciated.

Comment: What type of sparse matrix is it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I edited my answer to show the type.

Comment: I can explain the last error: calling `np.array(tfidf)` makes a 1-element and 0-d array of the entire matrix as an object.  To make it into an ordinary array, use `tfidf.toarray()` or to get a matrix, use `tfidf.todense()`.

Comment: Wonderful! That works and I can use linalg.norm() on the rows. Now I just need to figure out how to not make each row's norm equal 1. I thought that the entire tfidf matrix was being normalized and not each individual row...

Comment: I figured out a way to get the norm with the sparse form using `tfidf.multiply(tfidf).sum(1)`.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some simple fake data:

```
a = np.arange(9.).reshape(3,3)
s = sparse.csr_matrix(a)
```

To get the norm of each row from the sparse, you can use:

```
np.sqrt(s.multiply(s).sum(1))
```

And the renormalized `s` would be

```
s.multiply(1/np.sqrt(s.multiply(s).sum(1)))
```

or to keep it sparse before renormalizing:

```
s.multiply(sparse.csr_matrix(1/np.sqrt(s.multiply(s).sum(1))))
```

To get ordinary matrix or array from it, use:

```
m = s.todense()
a = s.toarray()
```

If you have enough memory for the dense version, you can get the norm of each row with:

```
n = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,a))
```

or

```
n = np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, a)
```

To normalize, you can do

```
an = a / n[:, None]
```

or, to normalize the original array in place:

```
a /= n[:, None]
```

The `[:, None]` thing basically transposes `n` to be a vertical array.

Answer (score 6):

`scipy.sparse` is a great package, and it keeps getting better with every release, but a lot of things are still only half cooked, and you can get big performance improvements if you implement some of the algorithms yourself. For instance, a 7x improvement over @askewchan's implementation using scipy functions:

```
In [18]: a = sps.rand(1000, 1000, format='csr')

In [19]: a
Out[19]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [20]: %timeit a.multiply(a).sum(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 288 us per loop

In [21]: %timeit np.add.reduceat(a.data * a.data, a.indptr[:-1])
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.8 us per loop

In [24]: np.allclose(a.multiply(a).sum(1).ravel(),
    ...:             np.add.reduceat(a.data * a.data, a.indptr[:-1]))
Out[24]: True
```

You can similarly normalize the array in place doing the following:

```
norm_rows = np.sqrt(np.add.reduceat(a.data * a.data, a.indptr[:-1]))
nnz_per_row = np.diff(a.indptr)
a.data /= np.repeat(norm_rows, nnz_per_row)
```

If you are going to be using sparse matrices often, read [the wikipedia page on compressed sparse formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Yale_format), and you will often find better ways than the default to do things.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the native scipy API `scipy.sparse.linalg.norm` ?

Read more at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.norm.html

Comment: that is a matrix norm