# Numpy matrix dimensions-tfidf vector

Tags: python, numpy, vector, tf-idf

Im trying to solve a clustering problem..I have a list of tf-idf weighted vectors generated by the CountVectorizer() function.This is the data type:

```
<1000x5369 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 42110 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I have a "centroid" vector of the following dimension:

```
<1x5369 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 57 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

When I try to measure the cosine similarity for the centroid and the other vectors in my tfidf_vec_list by the following line of code:

```
for centroid in centroids:
sim_scores=[cosine_similarity(vector,centroid) for vector in tfidf_vec_list]
```

where the similarity function is:

```
def cosine_similarity(vector1,vector2):
    score=1-scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(vector1,vector2)
    return score
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    sim_scores=[cosine_similarity(vector,centroid) for vector in tfidf_vec_list]
  File "/home/ashwin/Desktop/Python-2.7.9/programs/test_2.py", line 28, in             cosine_similarity
    score=1-scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(vector1,vector2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 287, in cosine
    dist = 1.0 - np.dot(u, v) / (norm(u) * norm(v))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 302, in __mul__
    raise ValueError(**'dimension mismatch'**)
```

I have tried everything including converting the matrix to an array and each vector to a list.But I get the same error!!

Comment: Looks like vector and centroid has different dimentions, so check this two vectors lengths

Comment: @ Michael Plakhov  Nope-They have the same dimensions:1*5369 which is what Im unable to understand

Comment: what kind of element in this vectors? i mean typical size?

Comment: @Michael Plakhov.."Todense" works...!

Answer (score 4):

`scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` appears to not support sparse matrix inputs. Specifically, np.linalg.norm(sparse_vector) fails (see [Get norm of numpy sparse matrix rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168881/)).

If you convert both input vectors (actually here they are row-vectors in matrix form) to dense versions before passing them, it works fine:

```
>>> xs
<1x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> ys
<1x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> cosine(xs, ys)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 296, in cosine
    dist = 1.0 - np.dot(u, v) / (norm(u) * norm(v))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 308, in __mul__
    raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
ValueError: dimension mismatch
>>> cosine(xs.todense(), ys.todense())
-2.2204460492503131e-16
```

This should be fine for only individual 5369-element vectors (as opposed to the whole matrix).

Comment: @HapeMask..I lost track of this question.I did the same thing.It works fine when the matrix is converted to a dense matrix.!..Its an interesting point to note while working with distance measures and sparse matrices.